# What is the difference between object access and file (system) access in Windows 10?

Tags: group-policy, security-policy

Regarding auditing specifically.

When I look at 'Audit object access' it says:

> This security setting determines whether the OS audits user attempts
>   to access non-Active Directory objects.. (*whatever the hell that means*)

And 'Audit file system':

> This policy setting allows you to audit user attempts to access file
>   system objects... If you configure this policy setting, an audit event
>   is generated each time an account accesses a file system object..

Can someone who actually knows anything about this stuff answer pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has many types of objects *besides files* which can have DACLs (permissions) and SACLs (audit policies) applied to – for example, registry keys, services, processes, printers, and all the stuff in [Object Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_(Windows)) such as windows, desktops, or device nodes (much like Linux's /dev).

So the latter policy applies to files and folders specifically, and the former applies to *everything else* that's not a file or folder. For example, you could enable auditing on writing certain registry settings or on starting/stopping the webserver service.

See also [Microsoft documentation on this topic.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-object-access)